# Count Distinct Times Out During Left Join

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table of products and sub-products. It's quite a small table at 122 rows total and only 3 columns:

```
| backend | sub_product | product |
|---------|-------------|---------|
| conn_go | go_update   | prod_go |
| conn_go | go_delete   | prod_go |
| conn_go | go_edit     | prod_go |
| conn_rv | rv_update   | prod_rv |
| conn_mb | mb_update   | prod_mb |
| conn_mb | mb_delete   | prod_mb |
| conn_mb | mb_edit     | prod_mb |
| conn_pr | pr_update   | prod_pr |
| conn_pr | pr_edit     | prod_pr |
| conn_ct | pol_edit    | null    |
....
```

I then have this daily partitioned usage table, which records how many times a user has used each sub-product. This table is **a lot larger** (186GB, 247MB per partition, 4.6M rows per partition):

```
| backend | yyyy_mm_dd | sub_product | x_id | user_id | count |
|---------|------------|-------------|------|---------|-------|
| conn_go | 2020-12-15 | go_update   | 10   | 3422    | 1     |
| conn_go | 2020-12-15 | go_delete   | 10   | 23445   | 2     |
| conn_go | 2020-12-15 | go_edit     | 10   | 2243    | 2     |
| conn_rv | 2020-12-15 | rv_update   | 10   | 245342  | 1     |
| conn_mb | 2020-12-15 | mb_update   | 11   | 5464    | 3     |
| conn_mb | 2020-12-15 | mb_delete   | 11   | 1424    | 2     |
| conn_mb | 2020-12-15 | mb_edit     | 11   | 21454   | 2     |
| conn_pr | 2020-12-15 | pr_update   | 12   | 224525  | 1     |
| conn_pr | 2020-12-15 | pr_edit     | 12   | 22424   | 1     |
```

If a `user_id` has not used a `sub_product` on a day then there will be no row for that `user_id` / `sub_product` / `yyyy_mm_dd` combination in the `usage` table.
I would like to count, per `x_id`, the distinct count of `user_id`s who have used each `product`. Below is a the output I'm looking for, based on the above sample data.

```
| x_id | product | usage |
|------|---------|-------|
| 10   | prod_go | 3     |
| 10   | prod_rv | 1     |
| 10   | prod_mb | 0     |
| 10   | prop_pr | 0     |
| 10   | null    | 0     |
| 11   | prod_go | 0     |
| 11   | prod_rv | 0     |
| 11   | prod_mb | 3     |
| 11   | prop_pr | 0     |
| 11   | null    | 0     |
| 12   | prod_go | 0     |
| 12   | prod_rv | 0     |
| 12   | prod_mb | 0     |
| 12   | prop_pr | 1     |
| 12   | null    | 1     |
```

---

What I've tried:

```
import pyspark.sql
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

products = (
    spark.table('my_schema.products')
    .select('backend', 'sub_product', 'product')
)

usage = (
    spark.table('my_schema.usage')
    #.where(sf.col('yyyy_mm_dd')).between('2018-08-11', '2020-01-20')
    .where(sf.col('count') > 0)
    .where(sf.col('x_id').isNotNull())
    .select('yyyy_mm_dd', 'x_id', 'user_id', 'backend', 'sub_product', 'count')

)

agg = (
    products
    .join(usage, on = ['backend', 'sub_product'], how = 'left')
    .drop('count')
    .groupby('x_id', 'product')
    .agg(
        sf.countDistinct('user_id')
    )
)

agg.show(30,False)
```

The above Python runs for quite sometime (30+mins) and eventually times out:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 157 in stage 136.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: Lost task 157.9 in stage 136.0: ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3068 exited caused by one of the running tasks)
> Reason: Container marked as failed: Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
> Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
> Killed by external signal

Also, if I uncomment the `where` clause then I get another error:

> "filter expression 'my_schema.usage.`yyyy_mm_dd`' of type string is not a boolean

**Q.** Is there any way I can better optimize my code in order to get my desired output?

---

**EDIT:** Using a broadcast join greatly sped up the join and allows me to get an aggregated count. However, my code still doesn't produce the intended output from above:

```
agg = (
    usage
    .join(broadcast(products), on = ['backend', 'sub_product'], how = 'left')
    .drop('count')
    .where(sf.col('product').isNotNull())
    .groupby('x_id', 'product')
    .agg(
        sf.countDistinct('user_id').alias('usage_ever')
    )

)

agg.orderBy('x_id', 'product').show(500,False)
```

**Problem:** In my output, I do not get a list list of products per `x_id` i.e. I am missing rows when x_id has no users using a particular product (I would like to see 0 in such cases). Looking at the sample data, my output does not show a row for x_id = 10, product = prod_mb and usage = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an error usually means that your big table exceeds executor memory during shuffle sort so executor was lost. It this case with a small table you should join the small table to the big one usin BroacastHashJoin:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

usage.join(broadcast(products), on = ['backend', 'sub_product'], how = 'left')
```

About when operator:

```
.where(sf.col('yyyy_mm_dd')).between('2018-08-11', '2020-01-20')
```

should be:

```
.where(sf.col('yyyy_mm_dd').between('2018-08-11', '2020-01-20'))
```

Comment: This half answers my question. The broadcast join works perfectly, sped up my query a lot and allowed me to get results. Though, my code still does not product my desired output. I've edited the original question but maybe a new question would be more suitable (?)

Comment: @stackq You should select distinct x_id then CROSS JOIN it with DISTINCT product frame to get all combinations of (x_id,product)  and after that LEFT outer join it with agg on x_id and product.

Comment: I submitted an answer based on your solution / comment. Do you think my submitted answer can be optimised further or simplified? If not, I will accept your answer but if it can be then feel free to edit your existing answer with my code simplified and I'll mark as answered as well :)

Comment: @stackq in the final join you can also use broadcast(agg)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @valex, I was able to come up with this - which seems to work quite well. It can probably be reduced / simplified:

```
import pyspark.sql
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

products = (
    spark.table('my_schema.products')
    .select('backend', 'sub_product', 'product')
)

usage = (
    spark.table('my_schema.usage')
    .where(sf.col('yyyy_mm_dd').between('2018-08-06', '2020-01-20'))
    .where(sf.col('count') > 0)
    .where(sf.col('x_id').isNotNull())
    .select('yyyy_mm_dd', 'x_id', 'user_id', 'backend', 'sub_product', 'product')

)

agg = (
    usage
    .join(broadcast(products), on = ['backend', 'sub_product'], how = 'left')
    .drop('count')
    .where(sf.col('product').isNotNull())
    .groupby('x_id', 'product')
    .agg(
        sf.countDistinct('user_id').alias('usage_ever')
    )

)

distinct_products = (
    spark.table('my_schema.products')
    .select('product').distinct()
)

ids = (
    spark.table('my_schema.all_ids')
    .select(sf.col('id').alias('x_id'))
)

cross_join = (
    ids
    .crossJoin(distinct_products)
)

final = (
    cross_join
    .join(agg, on = ['x_id', 'product'], how = 'left_outer')
)
final.fillna(0, subset=['usage_ever']).orderBy('x_id', 'product').show(500,False)
```